# C# .NET 3.5 CF on Windows CE, Changing row background color in a DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, compact-framework, windows-ce

I am using C# .NET 3.5 CF developing for Windows CE. I am working on a dataGrid and need to know how to change the background color of a row on the dataGrid. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to manually draw it.  [Here's a blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2007/11/11/datagrid-with-a-custom-header-and-selection.aspx) describing "selecting" a row, which is just painting it with a different color.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate the speedy reply.