# Setting Row Color based on Cell Contents in .NET CF DataGrid?

Tags: c#, .net, datagrid, compact-framework, windows-ce

I have scoured SO([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163481/c-sharp-net-3-5-cf-on-windows-ce-changing-row-background-color-in-a-datagrid) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408113/changing-row-colors-in-the-compact-framework-datagrid)) and elsewhere for this as well as giving it the "ol' college try" myself and while I can easily get the rows back color set to whatever I want, alternating or whatever, I simply cannot seem to apply that logic to work when my criteria is based on the content's of a Cell.

What I am trying to accomplish is if the contents of `Cell[3] == "IN"` then `Row Backcolor = Color.Green`.

I've read through this blog post([HERE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/netcfteam/archive/2006/04/25/583542.aspx)) and this one([HERE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2007/11/11/datagrid-with-a-custom-header-and-selection.aspx)) as well as downloading the example code provided on both.

Comment: This question --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19923549/set-forecolor-backgroundcolor-of-each-column-for-each-row-separately-in-net-c?rq=1 is actually closer to what I want but has no answers...

Answer (score 1):

override the Paint method in your datagrid column, read the cell value

```
Object cellData = base.PropertyDescriptor.GetValue(source.List[rowNum]);
```

add your logic to determine what color your background should be then call the base class Paint method passing in the background color you want to use